# Eclipse Scout 11 or 22 getting stuck

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-scout

I have projects running on Scout 10, today I decided I would start to play around with the new Eclipse Scout, so I downloaded the new version here :
https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2021-12/r

I also updated my node version, installed pnpm, and got the adoptjdk11.

So far so good, I create a new project, try to run the [webapp] all and I am getting stuck here : [image]

So what I have tried is to manually run a mvn clean install, then run separately the server and the ui by using the launchers, and I get the application running

So two questions, why the latest eclipse Build is using the version22.0.0-beta instead of version 11? also why it gets stuck with the webapp all launcher

[image]

When looking at the project creation log we can read this :[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why it gets stuck with the webapp all launcher.

This was a bug in that specific beta build that has been resolved in the meantime, see also https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1109904/.

> Why the latest eclipse Build is using the version 22.0.0-beta instead of version 11?

The Scout SDK plugins in Eclipse and IntelliJ are not bound to a specific Scout version anymore. When a new project is created, the newest version is used automatically, which may not always be ideal indeed. But there are good news: the next Eclipse release 2022-03 coming out next week will provide the possibility to select any Scout version.
Apart from that, you could also use the mvn archetype command to create a new project. Details can be found in this thread: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1110018&goto=1849821&#msg_1849821